# Custom CEditor Eclipse CDT not recognized

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-cdt

How can I choose to use my implementation of CEditor instead of built in one?

```
<extension
  id="highlighter.CustomEditor1"
  point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
     default="true"
     name="CustomCHighlightEditor"
     extensions="c,cusc"
     icon="icons/c_file_obj.gif"
     class="highlighter.CustomEditor"
     contributorClass="org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditorActionContributor"
     symbolicFontName="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editors.textfont"
     id="highlighter.CustomEditorC">
  </editor>
```

Is not working (no error, no changes). If I open a C file it's still opened with the old editor.

Edit:

When trying to change default editor like in this image:

[image: .c and .cusc editor]

It is only recognized for my created cusc extension like you see here:

[image: cusc extension]

So there have to be something that prevents to override the file association?

Also ceditor functionallity like folding or such things are missing in both filetypes :-/

**EDIT: Works now, had some preference errors**

Comment: Thanks for splitting this out as a new question.

Comment: Does the editor association work in other views, such as navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Specializing Content type

If you want to have your editor opened by default for some specific C files, you need to define your own content types and then associate your editor with that specialized content type.

For example [Ant extends](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/ant/org.eclipse.ant.core/plugin.xml) the base xml content type to define an ant specific content type.

```xml
<extension 
        point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes"> 
        <content-type  
            id="antBuildFile" 
            name="%antBuildFileContentType.name" 
            base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
            file-names="build.xml"
            file-extensions="macrodef,ent,xml,ant"
            priority="normal"> 
            <describer 
                class="org.eclipse.ant.internal.core.contentDescriber.AntBuildfileContentDescriber">
            </describer> 
        </content-type> 
    </extension>
```

The key thing is that ant files can be `.xml` files, but something about its content makes it different. Look at [`AntBuildfileContentDescriber`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/ant/org.eclipse.ant.core/src/org/eclipse/ant/internal/core/contentDescriber/AntBuildfileContentDescriber.java) to see how Ant distinguishes a build file from a plain xml file.

If you then look at the [plug-in XML](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/tree/ant/org.eclipse.ant.ui/plugin.xml#n24) for the ant UI, you will find the editor associated with the specialized content type.

### Changing Default Editors

If you simply want to change which editor is used by default for a C file and there are multiple editors available, go to *Preferences* -> *General* -> *Editors* -> *File Associations* and select the file you want (*.c) and change the default editor.